# How to add values from a Pandas Series to a Dataframe column without duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I have a dataframe called 'df':

```
  Value   Num
0 alpha     5
1 bravo     6
2 charlie   7
```

And a Series called 'series_to_add':

```
  New Value
0 alpha     
1 bravo     
2 delta
```

How can I combine the unique values of the series into the existing dataframe to get something like this:

```
  Value   Num
0 alpha     5
1 bravo     6
2 charlie   7
3 delta     nan
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

Comment: @QuangHoang series

Comment: That print out doesn't look like a series to me. Is it a series named `New Value`?

Comment: @QuangHoang sorry I manually wrote the output. When I print the .keys of the series I get 'New Value' and printing type gives back 'Series'

Comment: If your object is a series, make it into a dataframe first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `to_frame`

```
s=s.to_frame('Value')
s
   Value
0  alpha
1  bravo
2  delta
```

Then do `groupby` get the `first`

```
pd.concat([df,s]).groupby('Value',as_index=False).first()
     Value  Num
0    alpha  5.0
1    bravo  6.0
2  charlie  7.0
3    delta  NaN
```

Or `drop_duplicates`

```
pd.concat([df,s]).drop_duplicates('Value')
     Value  Num
0    alpha  5.0
1    bravo  6.0
2  charlie  7.0
2    delta  NaN
```

Or `merge`

```
df.merge(s,how='outer')
     Value  Num
0    alpha  5.0
1    bravo  6.0
2  charlie  7.0
3    delta  NaN
```